# Scopes and associations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I'm trying to return records where the association is either present or not:

I tried these scopes:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :availability

  scope :with_availability, -> {where{availability.not_eq nil}}
  scope :without_availability, -> {where{availability.eq nil}}
end
```

Comment: Which one doesn't work? Second one looks good (note the round braces `()` in first one)

Comment: Do you get any error? Could you please show `Booking.without_availability.to_sql`?

Comment: `"SELECT \"bookings\".* FROM \"bookings\" WHERE \"bookings\".\"availability\" IS NULL"`

Comment: what fields are you doing the comparison with? availability is a table. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yea availability is a table. ` Booking should have 1 Availability. But sometimes a booking gets created with an Associated availability (bug I haven't tracked down yet). So I'm trying to return all Bookings which might not have an Availability associated with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :availability

  scope :with_availability, -> { joins{availability} }
  scope :without_availability, -> { joins{availability.outer}.where{availability.id.eq nil} }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instance methods instead

```
def with_availability
  availability.present?
end

def without_availability
  availability.blank?
end
```

Comment: This wont work, I'm trying to get all records which match those conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is better way but this should work as well:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :availability

  scope :with_availability, -> {where(id: Availability.pluck(:booking_id))}
  scope :without_availability, -> {where.not(id: Availability.pluck(:booking_id))}
end
```

Also I tried to reproduce the solution by the link below but I didn't manage to do this (but it could be helpful):

[Rails - has_one relationship : scopes for associated and non-associated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724000/rails-has-one-relationship-scopes-for-associated-and-non-associated-objects)